# C# Parallel.For - Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración

Tags: c#, hilos, excepciones, bucle-for

Llevo varios días pegandome con esta excepción. No entiendo porqué salta ya que no hago ninguna modificación de la colección original. Para asegurarme me he creado una lista de sólo lectura. Por favor ¿podría alguien ayudarme? Ya no se me ocurre ninguna solución. Lo que quiero es completar una lista con los WI con procesado en paralelo (más adelante incorporaré operaciones más pesadas).

```
WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
"Select [State], [Title], [Work Item Type], [Changed Date], [Changed by], [System.ChangedBy], " +
"[Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps], [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity],  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] " +
"From WorkItems " +
"Where [Work Item Type] = 'Bug' AND " +
"[System.TeamProject] = '" + _codProyecto + "' ");

int numWI = queryResults.Count;
WorkItem[] arrayWI = new WorkItem[numWI];
arrayWI = queryResults.Cast<WorkItem>().ToArray();
IList<WorkItem> listWI = Array.AsReadOnly(arrayWI);

Bug bicho;
List<Bug> lob = new List<Bug>();
Parallel.For(0, numWI, j =>
        {
            WorkItem aWI = listWI[j];
            bicho = new Bug();
            bicho.Id = aWI.Id;
            bicho.ImageIndex = 0;
            bicho.Title = aWI.Title;
            bicho.State = aWI.State;
            lob.add(bicho);
});
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: Explica lo que tienes y lo que quieres lograr, además de lo que hayas intentado. Saludos

Comment: Actualizado. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es el acceso concurrente para añadir a la lista. Podrías solucionarlo usando un simple lock y quedaria asi:

```
 //En la definición de la clase:
    Object lockMe = new Object();    

    //En tu función

WorkrkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
"Select [State], [Title], [Work Item Type], [Changed Date], [Changed by], [System.ChangedBy], " +
"[Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps], [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity],  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] " +
"From WorkItems " +
"Where [Work Item Type] = 'Bug' AND " +
"[System.TeamProject] = '" + _codProyecto + "' ");

int numWI = queryResults.Count;
WorkItem[] arrayWI = new WorkItem[numWI];
arrayWI = queryResults.Cast<WorkItem>().ToArray();
IList<WorkItem> listWI = Array.AsReadOnly(arrayWI);

Bug bicho;
List<Bug> lob = new List<Bug>();
Parallel.For(0, numWI, j =>
        {
            WorkItem aWI = listWI[j];
            bicho = new Bug();
            bicho.Id = aWI.Id;
            bicho.ImageIndex = 0;
            bicho.Title = aWI.Title;
            bicho.State = aWI.State;

            lock (lockMe)
            { 
               lob.add(bicho);
            }
});
```

Aunque la mejor opción seria usar   [Concurrent Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)

Comment: Muchas gracias Gerardo. Pruebo y comento. No obstante, soy pesimista porque hice una prueba de recorrer la lista `listWI` sin añadir ningún registro a la lista `lob` y se producía la misma excepción. Como te comentaba: pruebo y confirmo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No funciona. Como comentaba, parece que el problema está en la naturaleza del objeto WorkItem de TFS y la lista que lo contiene `listWI`. ¿Alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Has intentado acceder directamtente al `arrayWI`en lugar de usar una lista?

Comment: Hola @Gerardo. En primer lugar muchas gracias por tu ayuda. La verdad es que no he probado el array. Lo volveré a intentar. No obstante, me sigue descolocando la excepción ya que no se toca para nada la colección...